# Best practice for the generation of in-repo protos when using Go Modules

Tags: go, grpc, go-modules

**tl;dr** A repo formerly configured to use `GOPATH` is now configured for Modules. All's good and better. However, protoc correctly (!) generates Golang code for protobufs defined within the repo in a `github.com/path/to/repo/protos` structure when I'd now prefer these to be generated in my sources, outside of `GOPATH`. I'm moving them to resolve this. Is there a better solution?

---

I have a GitHub repo. For the sake of discussion, let's call it `github.com/acme/toolbox`. In a subdirectory, I have protobuf files that include:

```
package acme.toolbox.v1;
option go_package = "github.com/acme/toolbox/protos";
```

When I was `GOPATH`'ing, all was well and `protoc` would generate Golang bindings in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/acme/toolbox/protos` and my code, importing `pb "github.com/acme/toolbox/protos"`, would work.

Moving to [Go Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) hasn't been pain-free but, the benefits outweigh the cost and I'm future-proofing myself and the code.

My issue is that I don't see how I can get `protoc` to generate the Golang bindings into my arbitrarily and outside of `GOPATH` located clone.

I'm moving the files after they're generated but this feels... inelegant:

```sh
cd ${TOOLBOX}
protoc \
--proto_path=./protos \
--go_out=plugins=grpc:/go/src
./protos/*.proto
mv ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/acme/toolbox/protos/*.go ${TOOLBOX}/protos
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main point of the `go_package` option is to define what the go package name will be. With that said, it can behave differently depending on what you set it too.

If `option go_package` is defined to be a valid go package name (e.g. protos), `protoc` will generate the files in the folder defined by `--go_out` with that package name. If `option go_package` is instead a path (e.g. github.com/acme/toolbox/protos), `protoc` will create the folder structure defined relative to `--go_out` and place the files there with the package name being the same as the last folder name.

Unless I am mistaken in what you are wanting to do, you can change `go_package` to be:

```
option go_package = "protos";
```

and change your `protoc` invocation to be:

```
protoc \
--proto_path=./protos \
--go_out=plugins=grpc:${TOOLBOX}/protos
./protos/*.proto
```

Doing that, the generated files will be placed in `${TOOLBOX}/protos` with the go package `package protos`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this approach would work. However, Go Modules provides the ability to define my project as e.g. `github.com/acme/toolbox` even though the files are stored in some arbitrary directory. This is because `go.mod` includes a `module` prefix that references that github path. If -- and perhaps this is my mistake -- `protos` is a subdirectory of the project, Go files in my project should refer to its files using the module prefix.

Comment: On reflection, this is exactly the correct answer. For some (stupid) reason, I was not thinking through the consequences of using `go_package` using a `${GOPATH}` value. You're, of course, correct. I revised `go_package` to be `protos` and the bindings are generated where I want them. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Jacob. The first sentence saved my life. Google needs to explain things in a simple way...